# Using React functional component as a Type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am able to use a React class component (i.e. `React.Component`) as a Type but unable to use functional/stateless components. Here is an example:

```
import Footer from 'path/to/component/Footer';

interface ComponentProps {
    customFooter: (Footer)
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<ComponentProps> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.customFooter}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Footer.tsx**

```
const Footer: React.StatelessComponent<{ children?: any }> = ({ children }) => (
    <footer>
        <div>
            {children}
        </div>
    </footer>
);

export default Footer;
```

The red underline is under the `(Footer)` and reads: `Cannot find name 'Footer'`.

I've discovered that if I use a React class component instead of a functional component, my issue goes away.  Why is it that I cannot use a functional component  and is there a way for me to do so?

Comment: you have a typo here:  `<footer}>`

Comment: Thanks for the catch. That was a result of me removing unnecessary css class attribute from my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Footer isn't a type it is only a variable, to get the type you could use `typeof`

```
const Footer: React.StatelessComponent<{ children?: any }> = ({ children }) => (
    <footer>
        <div>
            {children}
        </div>
    </footer>
);

interface ComponentProps {
    customFooter: typeof Footer    
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<ComponentProps> {
    render() {
        const {customFooter: CustomFooter} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {<CustomFooter>footer children</CustomFooter>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const MainComponent = () => {
    return (<MyComponent customFooter={Footer}/>)
};
```

if you want to add an actual jsx element as value like this:

```
const MainComponent = () => {
    return (<MyComponent customFooter={<Footer>footer children</Footer>}/>)
};
```

then you need to set the type of customFooter to something like React.ReactNode:

```
interface ComponentProps {
    customFooter: React.ReactNode
}
```